# Hosting a WPF window (by creating exe) in another WPF application and fixing the position of the hosted window into a pane

Tags: c#, wpf, hosting

I have created a very simple WPF window to host in another WPF application.

The name of the first WPF Solution is `SolutionToHost.sln` and the hosting WPF Solution is `HostingExeFileInWPF.sln`.

In the HostingExeFileInWPF.sln, the MainWindow.xaml file has the following content

```xml
<Window ...imports...
<telerik:RadDocking HasDocumentHost="False">
    <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft">
        <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            <telerik:RadPane Header="Left Pane">
            </telerik:RadPane>
        </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
    </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
    <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedRight">
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft">
        <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            <telerik:RadPane x:Nam="HostDock" Header="Right Pane">
            </telerik:RadPane>
        </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
    </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
</telerik:RadDocking>
</Window>
```

In the SolutionToHost.sln, the MainWondow.xaml file has the following content

```xml
<Window ...imports...
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="I am the application to host"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to embed the Window in the MainWindow.xaml of SolutionToHost.sln into to Right Pane of the hosting window so that whenever I move the Right pane, the hosted window will be inside that pane. Moreover, I want the size of the hosted window to change whenever I change the size of the right pane. I can explain further if my question is not clear enough.

So far, first of all, I created the ".exe" file of SolutionToHost.sln. After I created it, I created process in the MainWindow.xaml.cs of the hosting solution.

HostingExeFileInWPF.sln has the following MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    private Process process;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    private const int WS_CHILD = 0X40000000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndParent);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, e) => LaunchChildProcess();
    }

    private void LaunchChildProcess()
    {

        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("PATH_OF_EXE_FILE");
        this.process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        IntPtr childHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;

        int oldStyle = GetWindowLong(childHandle, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(childHandle, GWL_STYLE, (old_style | WS_CHILD));
        SetParent(childHandle, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    }
}
```

When I do this, the window of the SolutionToHost.sln, is as if embedded into the main window of the hosting window, however, I want it to be inside the right pane. When I move the main window (external window), the hosted window moves as well (like I wanted), however it has no relation with the right pane. (I guess) I want the right pane to be the parent of the hosted window. How can I achieve this?